# How do I create a button that will display hidden text when pressed using CSS?

Tags: css, button, text, hidden, buttonclick

I want to create a page where the user is prompted to click on a button. When they click on the button I want a text displayed below it, displaying whatever I choose the text to include. Everywhere I've looked has just told me how to make an input user text button which is not what I'm looking for. I would like the solution using CSS only please.

I haven't tried anything so far. I built the original page to display the text on hover, but it wasn't intuitive when using a touch screen device and I want to avoid text overlays telling the user things like "touch here" when I could just do a better job making the site feel more intuitive to touch device users. Like I mentioned previously I haven't found useful information for what I'm trying to create. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it's important that you make an attempt and show some code on Stack Overflow in order to get a good answer for what you need.

Comment: I think you need HTML rather than just CSS. Perhaps a details element, or input of type checkbox.